# Vuetify v-select prop type check failure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am constantly getting this error when I use v-select from Vuetify 3:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "title". Expected String | Number | Boolean, got Object
> at <VListItem key=0 title=`

I am unsure of what the issue is. I fetched from my backend API an array of objects in my JSON response. My goal is to display all username in the dropdown menu but when I select an item in the dropdown menu, I want to store that entire object in a variable. So for example, if I select 'Desmond' username in the dropdown menu, I want to store the object related to desmond, i.e., `{"username": "Desmond","email": "desmond@test.com"}`

```js
<v-select
  v-model="selectedItem"
  :items="items"
  name="username"
  item-text="username"
  label="Select Item"
  return-object
></v-select>
```

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Testing123",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      selectedItem: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchItems();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchItems() {

      axios
        .get("http://localhost:5000/items", config)
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
```

This is my `response.data`

```
[
    {
        "username": "Eric",
        "email": "eric@test.com",
    },
    {
        "username": "Desmond",
        "email": "desmond@test.com",
    },
]
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like the error is coming from this component... Are you defining and using a prop named `title` anywhere?  A [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/dyQWZWB) with your current code (fetch data replaced with static data) works fine.

Comment: @yoduh I checked my code but I don't see `title`. And I also dont have this `VListItemTitle` in my code. Not sure why

Comment: When my `response.data` is ["Eric", "Desmond"], it works perfectly fine. Only when I change to objects then the entire code breaks

Comment: @MoritzRingler I am using this version `"vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.4"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `:item-text`, which is [the name of the property in Vuetify v2](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-text).

In v3, the property was renamed to [`:item-title`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-title).

Change the name and everything works:

```html
<v-select
  item-title="username" 
  ...
></v-select>
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)